# Yii2 authorize net recurring payment error

Tags: php, yii2, payment, authorize.net, gateway

I have integrate authorize net recurring/subscription payment and it's working fine when I have debug then I find a successful response with valid subscription id, but in response I am getting fatal error.

Comment: Call to a member function getResultCode() on null receiving this error.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><ARBCreateSubscriptionResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd"><refId>ref1450967088</refId><messages><resultCode>Ok</resultCode><message><code>I00001</code><text>Successful.</text></message></messages><subscriptionId>3043388</subscriptionId></ARBCreateSubscriptionResponse> 

But the code $this->apiResponse = $this->serializer->deserialize( $xmlResponse, $this->apiResponseType , 'xml'); is not converting the xml into expected object.

Answer (score 0):

It is get resolved. We need to update the library from here https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-php/